# How to reduce number of js and css load time in my magento site poup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento

Folks,

I am opening a popup through ajax in my magento site. The issue is the page which i am calling need lot of js and css files to get loaded to make that page work properly. But in turn it is increasing the load time of my popup.

I thought of loading loading all css /js on main page itself.But as you guys know that once the popup opens it doesn't know the content of main page as it is just an different entity.

And ajax approach is required because i am sending product id.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at the content which you are requesting using AJAX.

Following things you can do -

> - Minify CSS and JS
> - Optimize your code which prepares the data for Ajax response.
> - Optimize Magento Collecions (if exist in response code)

It may help to decrease the load time.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below links ,

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching